# Angular 5: Animations won't trigger after build

Tags: angular

I have several (and simple) animations which work fine in desktop Chrome, FF and Android browsers when running the app with "ng serve".

But when I build the app and deploy it to a web server (Apache) the animations won't work on any browser at all.

Need help in solving this.
I can reproduce the error with the following steps :

1) ng new animtest

2) opened app.component.ts and pasted content below

3) modified app.module.ts to include 'BrowserAnimationsModule'

4) ng serve

5) when clicked Chrome and FF animate the animation correctly

6) Ctrl + c (server stopped)

7) ng build --prod --base-href /app/

8) copied content of 'dist' to Apache (folder /var/www/html/app)

9) in Chrome and FF opened http://localhost/app

10) animations don't work

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
 trigger,
 state,
 transition,
 animate,
 style,
 keyframes
} from '@angular/core';
export const collapseTrigger = trigger('collapse', [
 state('collapsed, true, void', style({
 height: '0',
 opacity: '0',
 overflow: 'hidden'
 })),
 state('expanded, false', style({
 height: '*',
 opacity: '1',
 overflow: 'hidden'
 })),
 transition('true => false, collapsed => expanded', [
 animate('300ms ease', keyframes([
 style({ opacity: '1' }),
 style({ height: '*' })
 ]))
 ]),
 transition('false => true, expanded => collapsed', [
 animate('300ms ease', style({ height: '0' }))
 ])
]);
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 template: `
 <div style="width: 700px">
 <div style="padding: 30px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);"
 (click)="collapsed = !collapsed">
 Click to expand / collapse
 </div>
 <div style="width: 500px; height: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: 'hidden'"
 [@collapse]="collapsed">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
 text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
 It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
 with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </div>
 </div>
 `,
 styleUrls: [],
 animations: [collapseTrigger]
})
export class AppComponent {
 collapsed = true;
}
```

app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 BrowserAnimationsModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ng --version :

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.2
Node: 9.2.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.5.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.36
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.2
@schematics/angular: 0.1.5
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Edit: Since I don't get any errors in browser console, maybe the animations don't get exported during build at all (?). Could this be an Angular CLI bug ?

Could anybody please run this component (above) and confirm the different behavior of the dev and built variants ?

Edit 2: same behavior when running the app with "ng serve --prod".

Edit 3: This worked : animations work when build-optimizer is turned off.

ng build --prod --build-optimizer false --base-href /app

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: No, no error (in browser console) at all :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this is a bug and is fixed with [20725](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/20725)

also see : 
[20685](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20685#issuecomment-348236486) and [20374](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20374)